# How much difference would it make to index a database table when doing SELECT on random

Tags: mysql, database, select

Recently, I have a developed a very simple web app for a survey. I am using MySQL to store my data. Each user gets one question "randomly" drawn from the database table. I need to know if indexing would help to increase the retrieval performance while "SELECT" chooses random records each time.
thanks

This is the SQL command I am using:

```
'SELECT * FROM iens2.review_phrases ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1'
```

Comment: can you show your SQL? in which way the randomization achieves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "random" number is the sequence number of a question's sequence column (without gaps), then indexing that sequence column is certainly helping:

```
WHERE question.sequence_no = :rand
```

If, however you just

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Then an index can't help. With

```
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET :rand
```

An index on the order by clause's field will help a little, but the performance is still worse than accessing your question by sequence number

Answer (score 0):

YES, **indexing** would definitely helps u. this will increase the performance

Answer (score 0):

It would help, picking them randomly needs to get to the data at some point, which indexes are for.